# How to write pattern for all other urls that basically goes for not found in django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I tried this,

> url ('', views.notfound, name='notfound')

But seems it doesn't work properly, for example, I have another url pattern define,

> url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),

So, if I go for `http://example.com/login/`, this works, but if i go for `http://example.com/login/?help=1`, then it falls into notfound category. How can I handle that?

Comment: You have to add a 404.html page in your templates directory. Also look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615572/how-to-display-custom-404-html-page-in-django). Also set `DEBUG=False` in settings. So the not found url page is redirected to this.

Comment: In djanog 1.6 or higher no view is required. Just putting 404.html worked for me.

Comment: Look at this link too [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception)

Comment: Note that GET parameters (e.g. `?help=1`) are not used to match url patterns. Only parameters captured in the url itself (e.g. `r'^some_object/(?P<pk>[0-9]*)/$`) are used to match a certain url pattern. You can't prevent `/login/?help=1` from matching `r'^login/$'` without involving middleware and redirects or something similar, and it is most likely unnecessary anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to create a page that is displayed when a URL is not found (i.e. a Http404 exception is thrown) you can create a template with the name `404.html`, and that template will be displayed any time a URL is not found.

Or if you want to define a custom 404 handler view you can define `handler404 = views.notfound` in your `urls.py` file. Then just create your `notfound` view, and that view will be used whenever a 404 error is thrown (and `DEBUG = False`)

This is a better way to catch any urls that are not recognized and display a friendly 404 page.

Comment: Ohh I like the second idea. How to do that? I meant, where do I add this line?

Comment: Anywhere in your urls.py file. How about just after you define your url patterns?

Comment: Also note that this will only be called when `DEBUG = False`, as some others have mentioned. Otherwise you'll see the 404 callback (which is helpful for development)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with regex like this:

```
url(r'^.*', views.notfound, name='notfound'),
```

Make sure put it at the end of the `urls.py`

I think you may need to do something when url is not found, if you just need the 404 page, then the single 404.html in your templates works. And remember ti set `DEBUG = False` in your `settings.py` to see the 404 page in development environment.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what your use case is.Both above comments were equally right enough if u want to display a custom 404 page .Had u need something else to know. Check this out->

pip install django-extensions

then read [this](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/wiki/Current-Command-Extensions)

then use the show-urls command to enlist all possible urls.

Do some manipulation or write testcases with assert to check not found urls.

Hope this is ok for your requirements or kindly comment with your suggestions cheers :-)