# How to place "any url" at the end of urlpattern list

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to place     `url(r'^', include('article.urls')),` at the end of the urlpatterns list, because after urlpatterns I have url for `MEDIA_ROOT`:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

So I need `url(r'^', include('article.urls'))` to be the last. 
I tried

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^'), include('article.urls'),
)
```

But it's not working.

main `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'firstapp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^redactor/', include('redactor.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^basicview/', include('article.urls')),
    url(r'^auth/', include('loginsys.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('article.urls')),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

article urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # Examples:
                       # url(r'^$', 'firstapp.views.home', name='home'),
                       # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
                       url(r'^articles/$', 'article.views.articles'),
                       url(r'^articles/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article'),
                       url(r'^articles/addlike/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.addlike'),
                       url(r'^articles/addcomment/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.addcomment'),
                       url(r'^page/(\d+)/$', 'article.views.articles'),
                       url(r'^', 'article.views.mainPage'),
)
```

Comment: Can you post both of you `urls.py` files?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's not working."

Comment: when going to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/, it causes an error. I fixed it just adding url of MEDIA_URL in main urlpatterns:url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^', include('article.urls')),

Comment: And what is the error that it causes? Can you please put the traceback into the question?

Answer (score 0):

You may need this in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^.*', include('article.urls')),
```

And in your `article.urls.py` you need this:

```
url(r'^.*', 'article.views.mainPage'),
```

You may want to check this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265195/how-to-write-pattern-for-all-other-urls-that-basically-goes-for-not-found-in-dja#answer-27265797)

Comment: I want it in this way: urlpatterns += patterns