# Can't login into Django admin 404 error

Tags: python, django

I currently cannot log into my admin in Django, I get a 404 page.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
No Blog entry found matching the query
```

UPDATE #3

**Last Updated:** Dec 17, 10 AM

**Status:** Still unresolved, could use some help

- **I've updated the error message at the top of this post, and yes, the error message is short.**
- I've included the url.py for the actual project, in addition to the app called blog.
- Fixed the migrations being out of sync
- There is no longer an error in the Terminal
- The problem might lie somewhere in models, views or urls.py

**THE SUSPECTS**

This code snippet relates to "startproject takehome"

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include("django_markdown.urls")),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog',
    'django_markdown',
)
```

These three code snippets relate to the app called "Blog"

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="list"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="detailed"),
)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.
class FullArticleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)

class FullArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    heroImage = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    relatedImage =  models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    body =  models.TextField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    gameRank = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = FullArticleQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("FullArticle_detailed", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    # def random(self):
    #   return self.get_queryset().order_by('?').values('title','author','heroImage','body').first()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-pubDate"]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models 

# Create your views here.
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    template_name = "list.html"
    # paginate_by = 2

class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.FullArticle
    template_name = "detailed.html"

# random = models.FullArticle.objects.order_by('?').values('title','author','heroImage','body').first()
```

Comment: Did you activate the admin page in your main urls.py?

Comment: Yes, I've already done that.

Comment: did you renamed 'order' as 'slug' ?

Comment: No, order was field=models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)

Comment: If you enable Debug mode in your settings.py, the 404 page should give you some helpful information about what it tried before giving up. Can you add that to your post?

Comment: @Edward I have Debug mode on. The error message is very short, though the most notable piece of information might be "No Blog entry found matching the query"

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20102227

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a problem with your schema as a result of migrations. There are a few things you can try.

Edit: Since I don't see the field `order` in your current models.py, it is probably best to go with option 1.

**Option 1**: Flush and resync your database. (Or even better, delete your database and resync - easy if using SQLite3). Find db.sqlite3 in your `blog/` directory and delete it. **Warning: You will lose all data if you do this.** Once that is done, run ./manage.py syncdb and don't worry about migrations (especially if running Django 1.7, which you are).

<strike>**Option 2**: Remove the field causing the error (if possible), run a migration, then add it back and re-run the migration.</strike>

**Option 3**: Find all orders and delete whichever two are not unique, then re-run the migration.

Comment: Could you break this down into step by step instructions?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to update the answer. Can you update your code to include the model that causes the error?

Comment: I've updated the question by adding my models.py and the migration that Terminal looks at when I run ./manage.py migrate blog.

Comment: I've added some instructions on how to delete and resync your database. These instructions will only work if you're using SQLite3. Have you modified your settings page to use something else like MySQL?

Comment: My migrations are finally back in sync and there are no errors in the Terminal! However, I still cannot login back into my admin. I still get a 404 error. So, the problem might just be something else, but I don't know what. Hoping you might be able to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help with that part of the problem Jamie. I made sure to grab all my data in a file called all.json. The solution was actually a lot simpler than wiping the database, but I had tried this line of problem solving previously.

Answer (score 1):

Update: ok the migration problem has been moved out of the way.

Update 2: ok so it isn´t lacking the admin url pattern

What is the case with your importing the blog urls in your main urls.py? You match everything that falls through the patterns r'^admin/' and r'^markdown/' as a blog entry. 
Now your request is "/admin", and because of the lacking of a "/" (slash) at the end, in stead of being matched against the first pattern, it is matched against the last one: r'^(?P\S+)$'. So now it looks for blog entry with a slug called "admin", and fails to find one, and hence returns 404 with a very clear discription. (next time don´t hesitate to include that in the question :)

I expect also that requesting "/admin/" *will* result in an admin page, because it would get matched against r'^admin/', because of the trailing /

better practice is to avoid conflicts between main urls and app specific urls by sub-url'ing your blogposts somewhat like this:

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names

---

before update:
Maybe you tried to make the order field unique after having non-unique values in it. Have you tried removing the whole database and rebuilding it? That would be my first suggestion.

It seems like there are some quirks in sqlite, I never use it basically. I would suggest also to try using something more mature like postgresql or mysql.

Comment: well at least one problem out of the way! But if admin isnt working, have you tried adding a route in urls.py? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf
hang on, i'll add it to my answer, because it seems the question changed slightly.

Comment: This is the right answer, you need to register a URL for the admin site in urls.py.

Comment: and as a final suggestion, don´t write "from . import models" and stuff, but be pep8y and write: "from models import FullArticle" see pep8 style guide. Remember someone else might have to read it.

Comment: I've added in my code snippet for the urls.py for the actual project (in addition to the app called "Blog"). A route in urls.py is not the solution, I had it there already. The problem is still not solved unfourtunately @xxor

Comment: ah my bad. I was confused by the ever changing question. Did you follow carefully the 7 steps on the doc page I posted?

Comment: did you add django interface for the models?

Comment: scratch that; that is not needed for admin site to come up.

Comment: which version of django are you using?

Comment: @xxor I looked at the 7 steps in that link you sent previously, but I don't think it was the most helpful. This is the error in full: 

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
No Blog entry found matching the query

I'm using Django v.1.7

Comment: aha I have an idea. I will update my answer according to it :)