# 404 Error "No Blog entry found matching the query" Django admin issue

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems logging into my Django admin, which might be a problem with a missing route. I've looked at a similar Stack Overflow question, but that person seemed to have a [different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510684/cant-login-into-django-admin-404-error) and no answer.

## **Error message**

*The error message I'm getting is short and basically says "No Blog entry found matching the query."*

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
No Blog entry found matching the query
```

*These two relate to my project*

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include("django_markdown.urls")),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog',
    'django_markdown',
)
```

*These three relate to my app*

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="list"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="detailed"),
)
```

### Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.
class FullArticleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)

class FullArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    heroImage = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    relatedImage =  models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    body =  models.TextField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    gameRank = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = FullArticleQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("FullArticle_detailed", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-pubDate"]
```

### views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models 

# Create your views here.
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    template_name = "list.html" 
    randomArticle = models.FullArticle.objects.order_by('?').first()

class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.FullArticle
    template_name = "detailed.html"
```

Comment: What line is this happening on, and in which file?

Comment: @TankorSmash This happens when I type in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

Comment: Right, but there has to be more information given. Throw in prints everywhere, or use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's ulrpattern regex's are greedy, i.e. they must match exactly.

So visiting the url 127.0.0.1:8000/admin will not direct you to the admin section, whose regex is `r'^admin/'`. You need to visit: 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ (note the final `/`).

The reason you get the error "No Blog entry found matching the query" is because Django thinks `/admin` must be and attempt to fulfill `r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$'` for `views.BlogDetail.as_view()` (who's regex you should modify to include a final `/`. e.g. `r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/'` and perhaps drop the `$` too--why specify an ending?

Also, why are you using `\S` vs. `\w`?

Comment: Glad I could be helpful--happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of issues. You've entered in the URL `http://127.0.0.1/admin` which will *not* match the regex `r'^admin/'`. Based on the error message, it almost looks like your `BlogDetail` view is getting called, so the URL routing has to be skipping the admin url.

Add the trailing slash to your requested URL and it should work.

I haven't tested this, it's just off the top of my head.