# Django admin page 404

Tags: python, django, admin

When I try to navigate to the admin section of my django app, I get a not found error:

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib   import admin
from app.views import View1, View2
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', View1.as_view(), name="view_1"),
    url(r'^another_view/(?P<pk>\d+)$', View2.as_view(), name="view_2"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib   import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^/', include('project.urls')),
]
```

project/settings.py

```
....
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static'),)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/media'),)
....
```

When I try to navigate to localhost:8000/admin, I get the following error:

```
Page Not Found (404)

Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='view_1']
^another_view$ [name='view_2']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, admin, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20102227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the app and project urls the wrong way round.

The project urls should contain the mapping for the admin, and include the app urls; the app urls in turn should contain the specific mappings for the app views.

The static stuff should still be in the project urls though; although you shouldn't need it in any case.

Comment: I'm not sure I've labelled them correctly, but switching them round doesn't work; all other URLs work as it currently is. If I switch them round, I get:

 Your URL pattern ('^/', (<module 'project.urls' from '/example/project/project/urls.py'>, None, None)) is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.

Comment: Because you need to wrap that second pattern with `url()`, like all the others.

Comment: If I switch them round, and add url(), when i navigate to localhost:8000, which previously took me to the home page, I now get a 404: Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^/

Comment: Ah, also, that pattern should just be `r'^$'`; no slash needed.

Comment: Well that worked for the homepage, but now any other page doesnt...localhost:8000/another_view now yields the same 404

Comment: Argh I'm really sorry, that should have just been `r''`. When you're including things at the base path you don't need any pattern at all.