# Page not found with Django (404)

Tags: python, django

In my django project, when I access localhost:8000 it says:

```
  Page not found (404)
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/
```

The urls.py is:

```
  from django.conf.urls import include, url
  from django.contrib import admin
  from polls import views

  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
  ]
```

The polls urls.py is:

```
  from django.conf.urls import url, include
  from django.contrib import admin
  from polls import views

  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
      url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
      url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
      url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  ]
```

The Django version is 1.10. Can anyone help me identify the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102227/django-404-error-page-not-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a route for `/` it seems, so `http://localhost:8000/` does not get you anywhere.

You wrote `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),` in `urls.py` so all the routes defined in `polls.urls` are to be prefixed with `polls/`.

You may actually want to go to `http://localhost:8000/polls/` (notice the **polls/**, because the route you defined as index is listed in the polls app.

Had you wanted to route your polls index to your url root, you should change `urls.py` to something like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and the forget about the `polls/` part in the urls.

Answer (score 1):

In main urls.py change

from

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
```

to

```
url(r'^$', include('poll.urls')),
```